# An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

While downloading an Android SDK(**ANDROID STUDIO 3.5.1**) to create emulator, I got the error below

```
Packages to install: 
- Android Emulator (emulator)

 Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 29.2.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5889189.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 
'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-5889189.zip': 
C:\Users\i00556\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation08\emulator-windows-5889189.zip (The system 
cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 29.2.1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Android Emulator (emulator)
```

The installation did not complete successfully, See the IDE for log details,

how to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried running Android studio as administrator ?

Comment: "See the IDE for log details"

Comment: Yes,@Swayangjit I ran Android studio as administrator only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to upgrade the emulator while the emulator is still running this problem occurs. To resolve this problem you need to close any running emulators, and try upgrading will fix the problem.